# Can we delete some rows from a partition instead of looping over all records of the big table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I'm new to `SQL`  and databases world, and I faced this situation:

I have a partitioned table by day : every day a partition is created and collects all rows added in that day.

But now we are trying to reduce the amount of data since the size of the DB is getting bigger, so we decided to delete some rows based on some conditions.

what we are trying to do is:  delete some rows of unused data only of last 2 days.
so my question is :

Can we delete some rows from a partition? if so, does it  delete data from the actual table and frees some space?
example :

```
  delete from MyTable where condition1 and time >= (sysdate -2) ;
  -- is it the same as (from a performance perspective)
  delete from Mytable partition (MyTble_Partition) where condition1;
```

does a fragmentation or rebuild of indexes after delete of some rows is needed in this case?

Please correct me if I'm saying stupid things. 
I will be grateful for any guidance , Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main rule: you almost never have the reason to access to partition explicitly.
Your predicates (join\where conditions) must provide all needed information to database for correct targeting to only needed partitions.
If you want to delete some data from last 2 days then YES it's ok to pass time>= predicate. Only needed partition will be scanned by Oracle.
You don't need to rebuild indexes. This work will be done by DBMS.

Your next question - clearing the data to have more space. This is a bit tricky.
You must imagine every partition of your table as "independed table" in DB.
In many aspects that is.
When you do DELETE you don't get any free space on your hard drive. You just get some "free space" in your table. You can use this space for further INSERTS.
But (attention!) you must to know that you **really** want to add some records in "that old day" partition in future.
If not then you got no profit from DELETE. At all.

[Also read this article to understand how to free real disk space after table rows deleting](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schema003.htm#ADMIN01401)

Comment: thanks @alexeyivanov for your reply.
I asked the question because I found some documentations about selecting data from partition like this example  : `select name  from MyTable partition(Part_MyTable_20200416); ` so in the case if oracle takes care of the needed partition to be scanned, when we need to select from partition explicitly like the query above? Thanks

Comment: shorter answer will be "never".

you may want to drop specified partiton if it's obsolete (be careful and see here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-40D491DB-7965-4935-AB7A-F8D2DADA33C0.htm),
but you don't need to use partitions explicitly in your business DML manipulations.

declarative SQL is a useful tool over table physics. always try to use it.
physical structure of table (even partitioning principle!) may be changed. and it must not to corrupt your business logic.

Comment: try to build sql plan and see how oracle do access to partitions in fact: (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231)

you'll see that if you pass strong enough predicate in your "where" clause then oracle only use one partition (try to use "=" to exactly specify the day). in case of ranges (>=, <=, between) you'll se "partition range" access. not FULL TABLE scan. only specified range. and it's OK!